# Where to place menu logic in Laravel?

Tags: php, menu, laravel

What is best conceptual place to put menu data logic in Laravel. If I use Menu bundle where to put it. In `Base_Controller` create additional function or something different?

Comment: For example getting menu elements from DB and add to Menu (bundle) storage, for rendering in views.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **Note**: this answer was written for Laravel 3 and might or might not work with the most recent Laravel 4

---

My favorite way of creating dynamic menu is achieved by separating the menu part from main layout and injecting the menu data via Laravel's Composer (don't confuse it with Composer PHP package manager, they are different things)

```
<!-- layouts/default.blade.php -->

<div id="header">Title</div>

<div id="menu">
    @render('parts.menu')
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

```
<!-- parts/menu.blade.php -->

<ul>
@foreach($menuitems as $menuitem)
    <li>{{ $menuitem->title }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Finally we can inject the variable via composer.

```
<?php 

// application/routes.php

View::composer('parts.menu', function($view){
    $view->with('menuitems', Menu::all());
});
```

This way everytime `parts/menu.blade.php` is called, Composer will intercept the view and inject it with `$menuitems` variable. It's same as using `with` on `return View::make('blahblah')->with( 'menuitems', Menu::all() )`

Hope it helps :)

---

**Edit**: If you don't like to have logics in `routes.php` you can put it in `start.php` and consider Jason Lewis' way of splitting the `start.php` into separate files.

Create a directory in `application` called `start` and fill it with some files.

```
    + application [DIR]
    \-> + start [DIR]
        |-> autoloading.php
        |-> composers.php
        |-> filters.php
        \-> validation.php
```

Then add these lines of code into the end of your `application/start.php`

```
require __DIR__ . DS . 'start' . DS . 'autoloading.php';
require __DIR__ . DS . 'start' . DS . 'filters.php';
require __DIR__ . DS . 'start' . DS . 'composers.php';
require __DIR__ . DS . 'start' . DS . 'validation.php';
```

You got the idea. Put the composer functions in composers.php.

Read the entire article here: http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-keeping-things-organized

Comment: I think you merged two answers in one!

Comment: In new versions, instead of @render('parts.menu') use @include('parts.menu')

Comment: @CornelAndreev: what's the difference between render & include?

Answer (score 0):

How about fetching the data in a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers) and using a [HTML macro](http://laravel.com/docs/views/html#custom-macros) for generating the HTML?

Laravel often has many ways of doing things. That said, this can probably be a little overwhelming and confusing at times.

Comment: In documentation about view composer is said that _"Composers are typically defined in application/routes.php"_. I use routes only for routing not for logic, is there solution without routes?

Comment: They have nothing to do with routes, you can put them wherever you want - usually in an extra helpers file.

Comment: Ok, and where to put this logic (Composer)? In Base_Controller function? This is my main question. I understand that there is many flexible things in Laravel, but don't know where to put them.

Comment: I usually create one or multiple extra helper files for things like view composers, custom validation rules or HTML macros, which I include from either start.php or routes.php.

Comment: View Composers lesson at Laracasts is one of the free ones https://laracasts.com/lessons/view-composers . Wasn't around back when this question was asked