# How do inject data into a layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to inject data into a layout (not the sub-view), but I have not found any method that seems practical.

These are the two ways I currently know of to accomplish this. The data I will be injecting is the page title, for simplicity.

### Method 1

```
// app/controllers/HomeController.php

protected $layout = 'main';

public function index()
{
    $this->layout->title = 'Page Title';
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home');
}


// app/views/layout.blade.php
...
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
...
```

### Method 2

```
// app/views/home.blade.php
...
@section('title')
    Page Title
@stop
...


// app/views/layout.blade.php

...
<title>@yield('title')</title>
...
```

Once again, neither of these methods seem to be ideal, but I haven't seen a better method so far. I feel like Laravel *must* have some method built in to handle this...

Comment: What do you not find _ideal_ about method 1?

Comment: There are several good methods of injecting data into a view, so it seems like there should also be a method for injecting data into a layout. Both of my examples are hacks more than anything else. After digging around the source code for a while I have yet to find anything, so I was hoping I was just missing it and someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: This `$this->layout->title = 'Page Title';` is not a hack, and is the preferred method to passing data in to a layout.  Alternatively, you can use `@section('title', 'Page Title')` if you prefer Method 2.

Comment: Well in that case, thanks for the insight. I just assumed setting properties directly wouldn't be the best idea. Also, I had never seen that way of defining section content -- @section('title', 'Page Title'). That's very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the setupLayout method in the BaseController to pass the data directly to the View::make call.

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if(!is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Page Title'
        );

        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout, $data);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the setupLayout method to access $this->layoutData:

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if(!is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout, $this->layoutData);
    }
}
```

Then set the following in your actual controller:

```
$this->layoutData = array('title' => 'Page Title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this ?

```
<!--app/views/layouts/master.blade.php-->

<html>
    <head><title>{{ $title }}</title></head>
    <body>
        <ul id="nav">
            @section('sidebar')
                <li>List Item One</li>
            @show
       </ul>

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    $data['title'] = 'LaravelFour';
    $data['newItem'] = 'New List Item';
    return View::make('home', $data);
}
```

This is `home.blade.php`, notice `@parent` which will output `<li>List Item One</li>` and the variable `{{ $newItem }}` in the `home.blade.php` will be replaced with the value of `$data['newItem']`, which means `New List Item`

```
<!--app/views/home.blade.php-->

@extends('layouts.master')
@section('sidebar')
    @parent <!--This will represent <li>List Item One</li> -->
    <li>{{ $newItem }}</li> <!--This is new data, will be injected in the layout-->
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

The `sidebar` in the layout will be

```
<li>List Item One</li>
<li>New List Item</li>
```

I think, this way you are injecting new data in the master layout, [is this what you are talking about](http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates). You may take a look at [View Composers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) and [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542688/where-to-place-menu-logic-in-laravel) too.

Comment: This only works when using the @extends method from within the view. I want to use the method shown in my example where you declare the layout within the controller. In that scenario, the title variable would not be in the scope of the layout view.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use View's *nest*  method...

**Namespace:** *Illuminate\View*

**Located at** *Illuminate/View/View.php*

```
nest( string $key, string $view, array $data = array() )
//Add a view instance to the view data.
```

**layouts/bluePrint.blade.php**

```
<html>
<div>
 <!--Some nested content goes here -->
{{$nested_content}}
</div>
</html>
```

**forms/loginForm.blade.php**

```
<h2>Login</h2>
{{Form::open(array
    ('route' => $form_route, 'method' => 'POST', 'role'=>'form'))}}

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('username', 'Username', array
        ('class' => 'form-control'))}}
    {{Form::text('username', $value = NULL , array
        ('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Username'))}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('password', 'Password', array
        ('class' => 'form-control'))}}
    {{Form::password('password' , array
        ('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password'))}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::submit('GO', array('class'=>'btn btn-default'))}}
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('test', array('as' => 'test', function() {
    $layout = View::make('layouts.blueprint');
    return $layout->nest('nested_content','forms.loginForm');
}));
```