# How to make a global header in laravel

Tags: templates, laravel, view, controller, persistent

I have a laravel website I'm making.  I'd like to have a dynamic header that's persistent across every single page (Just like how stack overflow has their notification bar on the top of the header.  It contains dynamic content).

Is there a way that I can build this dynamic header content and include it in every blade template without having to build it from inside each controller and passing it to the View that that controller is serving up?  I have a lot of pages and controllers and it just doesn't seem right if I have to go into every single controller method to include this code to build the header and then pass the header contents into the view.

I know one method to do this could be to simply have ajax fill in the header on each page load, but this seems inefficient since I'd rather have the sidebar contents be served up with the page all at the same time instead of having the page load, and then fetching the header contents with ajax.

I also thought perhaps I could call something from within my own custom BaseController class that all the controllers extend from, however, that would still have me passing in a variable into each View::make() manually.

Comment: It would be best to create a template which includes the header (and footer/menu or anything else that goes on every page).  Then you have your blade pages extend that template to fill in the content.  To make sure certain information is available to it all the time, create a view composer for it.  Have you looked into doing anything like this?

Comment: I have not heard of view composers.  I'm reading up on the documentation now.  Seems like this may be what I'm looking for :)  There was also someone else on a different question who suggested possibly overriding setupLayout() http://stackoverflow.com/a/16470649/107459.  But I'm going to first read up on View Composers.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a view composer for ALL views? So that I don't have to specify them in an array?

Comment: If you create the base template where your header/footer would go and all your other views would extend that, then you just create a composer for the base template.

Comment: Or even better (in my opinion) put the header in a separate view and include it with `@include('partials.header')`. Then you can attach the composer specifically to that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out View Composers was what I was looking for: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

`// define a variable that will always be present inside of your header partial
View::composer('_partials.header', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});`